# IN clause in sqlite

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

Hi i am using "IN" clause in `sqlite` but this is not able to get data.

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE colum1!=0 AND colum2!=0 AND colum3 IN ('Allah','is');
```

for this query code is i am using

```
NSArray* serch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Allah",@"is",nil];
    str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM database WHERE colum1!=0 AND colum2!=0 AND colum3 IN ('%@')",[serch componentsJoinedByString:@"','"]]
```

FMResultSet return  nil;

Comment: database is your tableName

Comment: at the same time serch is array , if you use this you are passed the direct array in single query

Comment: str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM database WHERE colum1!=0 AND colum2!=0 AND colum3 IN ('%@')",[serch componentsJoinedByString:@","]]
 try this

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as:

```
NSArray* serch = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Allah",@"is",nil];

NSString *str1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM (name of your database table) WHERE colum1!=0 AND colum2!=0 AND colum3 IN ('%@')",[serch componentsJoinedByString:@"','"]];

NSLog(@"> %@", str1);
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

> Note: You must add the data for respective names in database table..